# Data Compression Algorithm for Less repetitive pattern (redundancy)

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, data-compression, coding-theory, encryption

Context:

Lossless Data compression (source coding) algorithms heavily rely on repetitive pattern (redundancy)

Questions

Which data compression method/algorithm deals with less repetitive pattern (redundancy) specially ?

Comment: This question was previously closed because it is too broad and not suitable for this site in its current form.  Please don't just re-post the question; it's no more suitable the second time than it was the first time, and re-posting wastes people's time.  Instead, if you can improve the question to narrow down its focus, please edit the other question based on the feedback you've received.

Comment: Just noticed this was posted by a less reputed Jim2 :-(